# How to create a new configuration with CMake

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, cmake

I'm trying to create a NewConfiguration for my project:

```
set (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Release;RelWithDebInfo;Debug;NewConfiguration" CACHE STRING "Configurations" FORCE)
```

But when I run CMake, I have multiple errors:

```
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be
 built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_NEWCONFIGURATION
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be
 built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_NEWCONFIGURATION
```

I think I'm missing something...

I also followed CMake FAQ:

```
 if(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES)
   set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES Release RelWithDebInfo Debug NewConfiguration)
   set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "${CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES}" CACHE STRING
     "Reset the configurations to what we need"
     FORCE)
 endif()
```

But same errors...

EDIT:

If I do:

```
    SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_PLAYERVIEWER "-Wall -Wabi" CACHE STRING "Flags used by the C++ compiler during maintainer builds." FORCE )
SET( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_PLAYERVIEWER "-Wall -pedantic" CACHE STRING "Flags used by the C compiler during maintainer builds." FORCE )
SET( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_PLAYERVIEWER "-Wl,--warn-unresolved-symbols,--warn-once" CACHE STRING "Flags used for linking binaries during maintainer builds." FORCE )
SET( CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_PLAYERVIEWER "-Wl,--warn-unresolved-symbols,--warn-once" CACHE STRING "Flags used by the shared libraries linker during maintainer builds." FORCE )


set (CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Release;RelWithDebInfo;Debug;PlayerViewer" CACHE STRING "Configurations" FORCE)
```

It creates the new configuration, but I can not compile. I think flags are not correct. I am using **Visual Studio 2008.**

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I've just created 6 or 7 new configurations for VS2008 with cmake 2.8.4 (now it is days or even hours from 2.8.5 release) for simple hello world project.

```
The reason why your attemps failed what flags are  inccorect e.g. they must be /MDd no -MDd
You notation will work for GCC based compilers, not for VS.
```

What I recommend you is to get closest flags set and modify it then

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_FOO ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG})
# .. modifiy it - add or remove flags
```

also i noticed that cmake sometimes does not actually write to .sln or it is not always reloaded (well, I am running win7 on VirualBox maybe it is source of issues).

what i did is the following -

```
file(GLOB WILL_REMOVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*.vcproj")
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove -f ${WILL_REMOVE})

file(GLOB WILL_REMOVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*.sln")
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove -f ${WILL_REMOVE})

file(GLOB WILL_REMOVE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/*.user")
execute_process(COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove -f ${WILL_REMOVE})
```

at least it reloads files :)

however, sometimes i need to run cmake 2 or 3 times to see new configuration at visual studio (can be virtual box, cmake or visual studio bug - have no idea about it).

But, anyway, after 2 or 3

```
cmake ..
```

It WORKS!!!!

Comment: The "run several times ..." might be a visual studio problem, not a CMake one. Basically my experience is, that in VS2005 and 2008 (didn't use 2010 yet) reloading projects often does not work, so I always close the solution and reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

Despite the CMake FAQ, looks like there is something still a bit unimplemented for this feature request. There is even an open issue for it:

http://www.cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=5811

Monitor that bug in the CMake bug tracker to be notified as things are updated.