# build c++ in debug mode with biicode cmake

Tags: c++, cmake, biicode

As I am unable to change from release to debug build type, I wonder what am I doing wrong. I am working with Unix Makefiles.

In docs.biicode.com/c++/building.html says how adding SET() in the CMakeLists.txt adds variables to cmake.

I am new to cmake and biicode, and I tried all of:

```
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug)
ADD_DEFINITIONS(-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug)
SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
target_compile_options(my_program PUBLIC $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-Werror>)
```

but gdb says that "no debugging symbols found".

Another way, as states `bii --help cpp`, is passing to cpp:build parameters that will be passed to cmake, but calling

```
bii cpp:build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

yields

```
Building: cmake --build . -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
Unknown argument -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
```

but calling directly

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug --build .
```

works ok, and I don't know how to change the order in the `bii cpp:build` command.

Is all this a misconception, a sintax error, or there must be something else wrong? what is the best place to change between Debug and Release?

Comment: `SET(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` do not set build type like that, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460486/cmake-build-type-not-being-used-in-cmakelists-txt/24470998#24470998

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [biicode docs](http://docs.biicode.com/c++/cpp-commands.html#bii-cpp-configure-configure-your-project), it looks like you need to use the `bii cpp:configure` command to pass arguments to CMake, not `bii cpp:build`.

As @ruslo commented, it's not good practice to set the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` inside the actual CMakeLists.txt ([see his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24470998/2556117) for more details), so you probably want to do:

```
bii cpp:configure -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug
bii cpp:build
```

I realise you said you are working with Unix makefiles, but *if* you were using a multi-configuration generator (like Visual Studio), the build type doesn't get set at configure time.  Rather it gets set at build time.  In that case, I'd expect the biicode commands to be more like:

```
bii cpp:configure -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64"
bii cpp:build --config Debug
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I also found useful to double check, that, at least with makefiles, `bii cpp:build -- VERBOSE=1` shows the actual compilation command.