# How to create cmake build configuration without debug symbols and without optimizations?

Tags: c++, cmake

I think default configuration types one can describe like this:

```
Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
```

But I need new one:

```
MyConf         : w/o debug symbols, w/o optimization
```

So, how to create it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### About table

Configurations in terms of gcc/clang compilers (CMake `3.4.1`):

- Debug: `-g`
- Release: `-O3 -DNDEBUG`
- RelWithDebInfo: `-O2 -g -DNDEBUG`
- MinSizeRel: `-Os -DNDEBUG`

It means:

> ```
>   +---------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
>   |               | optimization | assert works | stripped |
>   +---------------+--------------+--------------+----------|
>   |     Debug     |     no       |     yes      |    no    |
>   |    Release    |    full      |      no      |   yes    |
>   | RelWithDebInfo|    good      |      no      |    no    |
>   |   MinSizeRel  |    size      |      no      |   yes    |
>   +---------------+--------------+--------------+----------+
> ```

So I don't agree with your `MinSizeRel` description because in this case I think both `MinSizeRel` and `Release` are stripped.

#### About question

As far as I understand you want no extra flags at all (no `-g`, `-O*` or `-DNDEBUG`). For `Makefile`-like generators:

```
> cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=MyConf -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MYCONF=""
> cmake --build _builds
```

For generators like Visual Studio you need to use `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460486/cmake-build-type-not-being-used-in-cmakelists-txt) answer):

```
> cmake -H. -B_builds -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES="Release;Debug;RelWithDebInfo;MinSizeRel;MyConf" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MYCONF="/Od" -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MYCONF=""
> cmake --build _builds --config MyConf
```

Comment: Thanks @ruslo! I think that's is what I need.
But what this args for cmake do:
`cmake -H. -B_builds`

Comment: @ruslo Not sure if this is something that has changed with CMake versions, but for some time now, I've seen RelWithDebInfo have NDEBUG defined by default, which means asserts become no-ops. This is on both Linux and OS X with gcc/clang. Perhaps you could re-check and update your answer if this is indeed the case?