# How to force CMake create only Debug and Release configurations on visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, configuration, cmake, projects-and-solutions

I have tried to set it from source

```
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES "Debug;Release" CACHE STRING "Debug and Release configurations")
```

and from command line on generation  - it does not help

[image]

Comment: Try checking the `Configuration Manager...`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cmake generators for Visual Studio do not set CMAKE\_CONFIGURATION\_TYPES](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661264/cmake-generators-for-visual-studio-do-not-set-cmake-configuration-types)

Comment: Did you try setting [the `FORCE` argument](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry)?