# How to capture $<CONFIG> into a variable in PRE_BUILD add_custom_command?

Tags: cmake

`$<CONFIG>` echos the correct configuration, but is it possible to store its value into a varialble? How?

The minimal example below seems to only need something akin to `set(currentBuildType $<CONFIG>)` in the `add_custom_command` or in the `GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake` which it calls, but I don't know what syntax might allow it.

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.0...3.26.3)
project(LinkLibraryWithoutConfigCmake VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(targetExe Main.cpp)

set(absolutePathToInstallTrunk /opt/somewhere/install)
set(currentBuildType unknown)

add_custom_command(TARGET targetExe PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "-- In add_custom_command echo:"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "   CONFIG = $<CONFIG>, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}, currentBuildType = ${currentBuildType}"
)
```

./GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake

```
set(currentBuildType $<CONFIG>)

function(GetBuildType returnBuildType)
    set(${returnBuildType} $<CONFIG> PARENT_SCOPE)
    message(STATUS "In function GetBuildType:\n   CONFIG = $<CONFIG>, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}, returnBuildType: ${returnBuildType}")
endfunction()

GetBuildType(currentBuildType)

message(STATUS "In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:\n   CONFIG = $<CONFIG>, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}, currentBuildType = ${currentBuildType}")
```

Here is the output of configure/build commands for a single-config (#1 and #2) and multi-config (#3 and #4) generator:

#1

```
cmake -S . -B buildNinja -G Ninja -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

cmake --build buildNinja

-- In function GetBuildType:
   CONFIG = `$<CONFIG>`, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , returnBuildType: currentBuildType

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
   CONFIG = `$<CONFIG>`, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , currentBuildType = `$<CONFIG>`

-- In add_custom_command echo:
   **CONFIG = Debug**, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug, currentBuildType = unknown
```

#2

```
cmake -S . -B buildNinja -G Ninja -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

cmake --build buildNinja

-- In function GetBuildType:
   CONFIG = `$<CONFIG>`, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , returnBuildType: currentBuildType

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
   CONFIG = `$<CONFIG>`, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , currentBuildType = `$<CONFIG>`

-- In add_custom_command echo:
   **CONFIG = Release**, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Release, currentBuildType = unknown
```

#3

```
cmake -S . -B buildNinjaMC -G "Ninja Multi-Config"

cmake --build buildNinjaMC --config Debug

-- In function GetBuildType:
   CONFIG = `$<CONFIG>`, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , returnBuildType: currentBuildType

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
   CONFIG = `$<CONFIG>`, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , currentBuildType = `$<CONFIG>`

-- In add_custom_command echo:
   **CONFIG = Debug**, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , currentBuildType = unknown
```

#4

```
cmake --build buildNinjaMC --config Release

-- In function GetBuildType:
   CONFIG = `$<CONFIG>`, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , returnBuildType: currentBuildType

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
   CONFIG = `$<CONFIG>`, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , currentBuildType = `$<CONFIG>`

-- In add_custom_command echo:
   **CONFIG = Release**, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , currentBuildType = unknown
```

Please notice that in each case the last line gives the correct value for CONFIG, therefore it seems it should be possible to capture it, but how?

The purpuse of this would be to append the `currentBuildType` to `absolutePathToInstallTrunk` so that a correct imported library can be linked (this is for import libraries without *Config.cmake), e.g. in CMake script there also would be:

```
add_library(StaticLib::StaticLib STATIC IMPORTED)

include(GNUInstallDirs)

target_include_directories(StaticLib::StaticLib
    INTERFACE
        ${absolutePathToInstallTrunk}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR}
)

set_target_properties(StaticLib::StaticLib
    PROPERTIES
        IMPORTED_LOCATION ${absolutePathToInstallTrunk}/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}/${currentBuildType}/libStaticLibName.a
)
```

I tried a naive approach:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET targetExe PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND set(currentBuildType $<CONFIG>)
)
```

This configures, but the build fails with:

```
Environment variable ( currentBuildType Debug )  not defined

ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I also tried setting CONFIG to a variable inside a function which returns the variable in parent_scope:

```
function(GetBuildType returnBuildType)
    set(${returnBuildType} $<CONFIG> PARENT_SCOPE)
```

the function is called in add_custom_command via a script:

```
COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake
```

but the value is not set as shown in the output earlier above.

Comment: The CMake script you invoke inside `add_custom_command` is run NOT in the context of the `CMakeLists.txt`, so it has no access to any variable/target/generator expression which is defined in the `CMakeLists.txt`. You may, however, pass the **parameter** to that script via regular `-D` option: `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -DcurrentBuildType=$<CONFIG> -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you for the idea, but I looks like there is something elusive about $<CONFIG> itself: other normal variables can indeed be passed to GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake and used there, but $<CONFIG> remains blank even when passed in as a parameter like you've shown. The output is the same as before, i.e. only at the point of echo in add_custom_command $<CONFIG> produces the correct value.

Comment: "... but $<CONFIG> remains blank even when passed in as a parameter like you've shown." - What do you mean by "remains blank"? None of your printing prints `$<CONFIG>` as blank. If you are about `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`, then inside the script `GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake` that variable is not defined (see the last paragraph of [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77205819/3440745)), so it is printed as blank. Inside that script you need to use `currentBuildType` variable for refer to the build type.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i misspoke, it is not "blank", I meant to convey that `$<CONFIG>` doesn't carry a proper value like "Debug" or "Release". I just tried using and printing `${currentBuildType}` within the GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake (both outside and inside the function GetBuildType, but its value there is the literal "`$<CONFIG>`". However, you just gave a similar idea which works for my purpose, I will jot it down in the answer below. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a generator expression is that it is evaluated / expanded during the *generation* phase and not during the configuration phase so that it can expand to values that vary depending on the build configuration with multi-config generators. The value will be expanded at generation time. Until generation time (during configuration time, the generator expression will be just that: a generator expression). CMake variables in the configuration scripts are evaluated at configuration time.

FYI a lot of the things you have attempted are... weird. For one thing, running another CMake in script mode as a custom command, that script-mode-CMake (as far as I know) isn't going to do anything for generator expressions, because it's script mode- it's not generating a buildsystem. So an attempt to use `$<CONFIG>` will just be treated as a string.

When you try to pass a variable to a function, you either need to use a variable (de)reference to pass the value and use the value in the function, or pass the name of the variable, and "dereference" that in the function. Your `GetBuildType(currentBuildType)` passes the name of the variable to the function, and your function just dereferences its parameter name to get the string `currentBuildType`.

Your attempts to refer to `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in your custom command invocation of a CMake script expand to nothing because the script has no such variable and non-existent variables expand to nothing. To actually have the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable from the CMake configuration in the script-mode-CMake it invokes, it would need to pass that variable to the script using [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-P-D).

Custom commands are run during build, which is after generation of the buildsystem. Generator expressions are evaluated during the generation phase, which is during the generation of the buildsystem. So if you want to use a generator expression in a custom command... Just do it. If you want to pass the evaluated value to a script called in the custom command... Just do it. `COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake "-DCONFIG=$<CONFIG>"`. Then in GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake, the evaluated value of the `$<CONFIG>` generator expression will be in a variable named `CONFIG`.

And no, there is no trick to get the evaluated generator expression in a CMake script called as part of a custom command and then get that value back in the configuration script that configured the custom command. Again, the custom command is run during build time- completely after the generation of the buildsystem has completed. And the `$<CONFIG>` generator expression (and other generator expressions) are *purposely* not evaluated until the generation phase because it's not possible to simultaneously have multiple separate, different values in a variable during the configuration phase.

Comment: I was attempting to return a value of the variable `returnBuildType` from the function GetBuildType, that's why in the body I used `set(${returnBuildType} currentBuildType PARENT_SCOPE)` instead of `set(returnBuildType currentBuildType PARENT_SCOPE)`.

It is indeed weir/unintuitive in CMake, but [this blog](https://markdewing.github.io/blog/posts/notes-on-cmake/) gave a helpful insight.

Comment: @Mariusz see edit (I added a paragraph at the end).

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler solution with corrections based on comments above:

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.0...3.26.3)
project(Empty VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(targetExe Main.cpp)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(absolutePathToInstalledLibrary /opt/somewhere/install/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

add_custom_command(TARGET targetExe PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D arg1=${absolutePathToInstalledLibrary} -D arg2=$<CONFIG> -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "-- In add_custom_command echo:"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "   absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = ${absolutePathToInstalledLibrary}"
)
```

./GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake

```
set(installDirValidOnlyInThisScript ${arg1}/${arg2})

message(STATUS "In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:\n   installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = ${installDirValidOnlyInThisScript}")
```

The output is:

#1

```
cmake -S . -B buildNinja -G Ninja -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

cmake --build buildNinja

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
   installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = /opt/somewhere/install/lib/Debug

-- In add_custom_command echo:
   absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = /opt/somewhere/install/lib
```

#2

```
cmake -S . -B buildNinja -G Ninja -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

cmake --build buildNinja

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
   installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = /opt/somewhere/install/lib/Release

-- In add_custom_command echo:
   absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = /opt/somewhere/install/lib
```

#3

```
cmake -S . -B buildNinjaMC -G "Ninja Multi-Config"

cmake --build buildNinjaMC --config Debug

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
   installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = /opt/somewhere/install/lib/Debug

-- In add_custom_command echo:
   absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = /opt/somewhere/install/lib
```

#4

```
cmake -S . -B buildNinjaMC -G "Ninja Multi-Config"

cmake --build buildNinjaMC --config Release

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
   installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = /opt/somewhere/install/lib/Release

-- In add_custom_command echo:
   absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = /opt/somewhere/install/lib
```

Answer (score -1):

Passing `currentBuildType` as a parameter to the script (as suggested by @Tsyvarev):

COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D currentBuildType=$ -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake

did not yield a valid configuration in that script, i.e. printing ${currentBuildType} gives the literal string "`$<CONFIG>`" instead of "Debug", "Release", or "RelWithDebInfo". But following this idea, here are modified scripts that can work - provided that the configuration value is only used in the called script and is not needed it in the main CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26.0...3.26.3)
project(LinkLibraryWithoutConfigCmake VERSION 0.0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

add_executable(targetExe Main.cpp)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
set(absolutePathToInstalledLibrary /opt/somewhere/install/${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})

add_custom_command(TARGET targetExe PRE_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=$<CONFIG> -D installDir=${absolutePathToInstalledLibrary} -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "-- In add_custom_command ECHO:"
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "   CONFIG = $<CONFIG>, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}, absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = ${absolutePathToInstalledLibrary}"
)
```

./GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake

```
set(absolutePathToInstalledLibrary ${installDir}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}) # unfortunately this does not affect the "same" variable in parent CMakeLists.txt
set(installDirValidOnlyInThisScript ${installDir}/${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE})

message(STATUS "In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:\n   CONFIG = $<CONFIG>, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}, installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = ${installDirValidOnlyInThisScript}")
```

The output shows that the relvant configuration has indeed been captured for both single-config and multi-config generator, but it persists only in the called script, i.e. the path to installed library has a currect subdirectory appened - be it "/Debug/" or /Release/" - but somewhat unfortunately only in the called script:

#1

cmake -S . -B buildNinja -G Ninja -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug

cmake --build buildNinja

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
CONFIG = $, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug, installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = /opt/somewhere/install/lib/Debug

-- In add_custom_command ECHO:
CONFIG = Debug, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug, absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = /opt/somewhere/install/lib

#2

cmake -S . -B buildNinja -G Ninja -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

cmake --build buildNinja

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
CONFIG = $, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Release, installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = /opt/somewhere/install/lib/Release

-- In add_custom_command ECHO:
CONFIG = Release, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Release, absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = /opt/somewhere/install/lib

#3

cmake -S . -B buildNinjaMC -G "Ninja Multi-Config"

cmake --build buildNinjaMC --config Debug

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
CONFIG = $, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug, installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = /opt/somewhere/install/lib/Debug

-- In add_custom_command ECHO:
CONFIG = Debug, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = /opt/somewhere/install/lib

#4

cmake -S . -B buildNinjaMC -G "Ninja Multi-Config"

cmake --build buildNinjaMC --config Release

-- In GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake:
CONFIG = $, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Release, installDirValidOnlyInThisScript = /opt/somewhere/install/lib/Release

-- In add_custom_command ECHO:
CONFIG = Release, CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = , absolutePathToInstalledLibrary = /opt/somewhere/install/lib

Notice that the variable `installDirValidOnlyInThisScript` has a correct value each time, but back in the parent CMakeLists.txt the value of `absolutePathToInstalledLibrary` does not have a configuration-named subdirectory appended.

Comment: it's not "persisting only in the called script". It's evaluated during the generation phase, which is during the generation of the buildsystem. custom commands are called during build, which is always after generation of the buildsystem.

Comment: Sorry about typos in the answer: `$<CONFIG>` doesn't show up correctly (can't seem to edit now). Wherever you see just a lone "$" it should actually be `$<CONFIG>`.

Comment: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting). it's being treated as a xml/html tag. you either need to escape the `<` and `>` by writing `\<` and `\>`, or wrap it as code using backticks.

Comment: For single-config generators this whole contraption is redundant because passing CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE as commandline argument is sufficient. But this attempt is to make it work also for multiconfig generators, where CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is not passed as an argument, bit instead at the build step the flag is given: `--config <Debug/Release>

Comment: yes, I know. [this is not news to me](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76986470/11107541). why are you telling me?

Comment: "printing ${currentBuildType} gives the literal string "$<CONFIG>" - This is, probably, because you haven't deleted the line `set(currentBuildType $<CONFIG>)` from your script, which redefines the variable passed as the parameter.

Comment: You are right, there was interference from `set(currentBuildType $<CONFIG>)` at the top of my initial ./GetCurrentConfiguration.cmake. So below is a simplified solution.