# how to generate pdb files for Release build with cmake flags?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, cmake, pdb-files

I am generating a visual studio solution using cmake. And now I want to generate pdb files for a Release build. (Why? because I want to have the symbols in case that the user found some bug)

I tried by setting the following flags without succeed:

```
set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CACHE STRING "Build Types" FORCE)

IF(WIN32)

set( CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Release")
set( CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/debug /INCREMENTAL")
set( CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/debug /INCREMENTAL")
set( CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "/debug /INCREMENTAL")
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG")
set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "/MD /Zi /O2 /Ob1 /D NDEBUG")
ENDIF(WIN32)
```

It looks like Cmake is ignoring these sets:
thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Can you elaborate on - without succeed? Do you receive an error, missing results or just doesn't work?

Comment: Just doesn't work. I wonder if the line "set(CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES ${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE} CACHE STRING "Build Types" FORCE)" is overwriting the flags

Comment: I tried this in addition to ```add_executable(out a.cpp b.cpp)``` and when I built the Release configuration there was also a .pdb file. And it was debuggable. Could you post more details? And btw don't use ```CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE``` when generating for MSVC

Answer (score 19):

I used the flags

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE} /Zi")
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE} /DEBUG /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF")
```

[This site](http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jrobbins/correctly-creating-native-c-release-build-pdbs) explains the details

Comment: `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE` is a globally cached variable so I had to add `CACHE STRING "" FORCE`. Also make sure to use `CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE` and `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE` vars as appropriate.

Comment: There is no CMake documentation available for the variables `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE` & `CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE`. Where did you find them?

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: @DrumM, not much of a documentation, but there are https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG.html and https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_CONFIG.html

Comment: The linked article explaining the details moved here:
https://www.wintellect.com/correctly-creating-native-c-release-build-pdbs/

Comment: Above mentioned article's link is now: https://training.atmosera.com/correctly-creating-native-c-release-build-pdbs/

Comment: At the second line, I used CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE (instead of CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE) to have pdb file for the exe (instead of shared libs).

Answer (score 10):

Another way to do it is to use `cmake` generator expressions (https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), e.g.:

for all targets and all configurations:

```
add_compile_options("$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:/Zi>")
add_link_options("$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:/DEBUG>")
add_link_options("$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:/OPT:REF>")
add_link_options("$<$<NOT:$<CONFIG:Debug>>:/OPT:ICF>")
```

for particular target and `Release` configuration only:

```
target_compile_options(my_exe PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/Zi>")
target_link_options(my_exe PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/DEBUG>")
target_link_options(my_exe PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/OPT:REF>")
target_link_options(my_exe PRIVATE "$<$<CONFIG:Release>:/OPT:ICF>")
```

Comment: Also, add_link_options and add_compile_options worked for me while extending the CMAKE_* variables (like in the reply from 2015) didn't work for me.

Comment: You don't need to copy-paste the lines though, multiple options can be passed to the compiler with generator expressions too. IIRC with ; separating them and quotes around the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

In 'Modern Cmake' you can set this per target, this is the way to go:

```
if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "MSVC" AND CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Release")
   target_compile_options(${TARGET_NAME} PRIVATE /Zi)

   # Tell linker to include symbol data
    set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES 
        LINK_FLAGS "/INCREMENTAL:NO /DEBUG /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF"
    )

    # Set file name & location
    set_target_properties(${TARGET_NAME} PROPERTIES 
        COMPILE_PDB_NAME ${TARGET_NAME} 
        COMPILE_PDB_OUTPUT_DIR ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
    )
endif()
```

These flags are `MSVC` specific not `WIN32`.

Comment: Well, in modern CMake you should use generator expressions, since value of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is undefined for MSVC during configuration step. See accepted answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460486/cmake-build-type-not-being-used-in-cmakelists-txt

Comment: But as the answer says by using ‘-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug’, it is defined at config time, right? Then you can use ‘if (CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL Release)’. We do it all the time

Comment: Well, the issue is that you can pass `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug` in configuration time and then build the project as Release in Visual Studio (generation time). Thus relying on `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` in configuration time for multiple-configuration IDEs (including VS) is not reliable. E.g. in your code case you can do the opposite, pass `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` as `Release` and then build project via IDE as `Debug` and you will most likely get duplicated `"/INCREMENTAL:NO /DEBUG /OPT:REF /OPT:ICF"` flags. I agree, this may be not harmfull in this case, but can break build in others.

Comment: After rereading my comment I think I might have not expressed the point, which is: you should not pass  `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` for Visual Studio at all, as it is not used by it. To quote the docs: "This variable is only meaningful to single-configuration generators". https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html Whenever you use it in your code, you should treat it no different than any other user-defined variable e.g. `MY_BUILD_TYPE` variable. Without generator expressions your approach is only half-way of being "Modern CMake".

Comment: That's true! But who says I want to use Visual Studio :-) 
The only thing I find strange is that you have to do the same generator expressions for the other calls: `set_target_properties` and `set_target_properties`. Like 1 `if` doesn't suffice

Comment: This question is tagged `visual-studio`, so you should assume so in your answer.

Comment: -1 for the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` issue. It is never valid to read that variable without an explicit check that the active generator is single-config.

Comment: You're right @AlexReinking, I need an update!