# Set the directory for Intermediate files (like .obj) in CMake

Tags: cmake

I've seen that CMake put the intermediate files, like .obj in a directory like this :

```
project.dir/sort/of/copy/of/source/directory
```

Is there a way to have something like that :

```
project.dir/Debug/ myfiles.obj    |--> for my debug
```

and

```
project.dir/Release/ myfiles.obj    |--> for my release
```

For moment, I used 2 separate directory to generate each time my libraries or executable for the Debug and the release. And after I have also the platform...

Is there something similar to CMAKE_ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE or CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE...

for intermediate files.obj ?

I've try too the `/Fo` but when I used this FLAG, Cmake override with his configuration :

`warning D9025 : overriding '/Fo;../x64/Debug/' with '/FoCMakeFiles\project.dir\src\project\main.cpp.obj'`

Please, does someone have a solution ?

Comment: Using two build directories seems to be the most natural way to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't - at least at the moment, see [0014999: Changing Intermediate Directory of Visual Studio 2012](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/14999) feature request - change the intermediate directories in CMake and for makefile generators - like in your case `NMake` - you can have only one [build configuration type](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html) per binary build output directory.

So as @usr1234567 has commented, using two build directories is the right thing to do.

Or - if this is an option - use the Visual Studio multi-configuration generator. It does exactly use the intermediate directories you have suggested:

```
project.dir/Debug/...
project.dir/Release/...
```

**NMake vs. Visual Studio Solution on the Command Line**

The differences can also be seen in the wrapper scripts I normally use to build my CMake based systems.

So `NMake` would look something like this:

```
@ECHO off
"\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\vc\vcvarsall.bat" x64
IF NOT EXIST "x64\Debug\Makefile" (
    cmake -H"." -B"x64/Debug" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G"NMake Makefiles"
)
cmake --build "x64/Debug" --target "project"
IF NOT EXIST "x64\Release\Makefile" (
    cmake -H"." -B"x64/Release" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -G"NMake Makefiles"
)
cmake --build "x64/Release" --target "project"
```

And my prefered Visual Studio Solution variant something like this:

```
@ECHO off
IF NOT EXIST "x64\*.sln" (
    cmake -H"." -B"x64" -G"Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64"
)
cmake --build "x64" --target "project" --config "Debug"
cmake --build "x64" --target "project" --config "Release"
```

**Additional References**

- [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE is not being used in CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460486/cmake-build-type-not-being-used-in-cmakelists-txt)
- [CMake build multiple targets in different build directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999130/cmake-build-multiple-targets-in-different-build-directories)
- [CMake: how to specify the version of Visual C++ to work with?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33917454/cmake-how-to-specify-the-version-of-visual-c-to-work-with)
- [The Architecture of Open Source Applications - CMake](http://aosabook.org/en/cmake.html)