# How to instruct CMake to use the build architecture compiler

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling

When using CMake for cross compiling, one generally specifies a toolchain file via the `CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE` option. In [GNU terminology](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Cross_002dCompilation.html), one can specify the host architecture toolset using this file. However, one can generally not expect to be able to execute anything built with this toolchain. So often enough, some build tools need to be compiled for the build architecture.

Consider the following setup. I have two source files `genfoo.c` and `bar.c`. During build, `genfoo.c` needs to be compiled and run. Its output needs to be written to `foo.h`. Then I can compile `bar.c`, which `#include "foo.h"`. Since CMake defaults to using the host architecture toolchain, the instructions for `bar.c` are easy. But how do I tell it to use the build architecture toolchain for compiling `genfoo.c`? Simply saying `add_executable(genfoo genfoo.c)` will result in using the wrong compiler.

Comment: As you have stated, in GNU terminology you would use the `configure` command to specify the host architecture. And you would have to run `configure` twice if you want to build for two different host environments. So I see two possibilities with CMake: use a build script that creates and executes the two environments needed (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999130/cmake-build-multiple-targets-in-different-build-directories)) or use [ExternalProject_Add()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.2/module/ExternalProject.html) and split your `CMakeLists.txt` into dedicated subprojects.

Comment: No, with autotools you simply use `CC_FOR_BUILD`. See `ax_cc_for_build`.

Comment: Ok, didn't know that one. If I understand correctly we are talking about the use case described in [CMake Cross Compiling - Using executables in the build created during the build](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#Using_executables_in_the_build_created_during_the_build)?

Comment: @Florian I believe that you should make an answer with that link as it answers a huge part of my question. I don't like the approach taken, but it certainly solves the problem at hand. I was originally blind to recognizing this as a solution as it puts the burdon (of building twice) on the user.

Comment: If you know the other compiler's path (like you probably need to with `CC_FOR_BUILD`) and the parameters you like to call it with, there are other possibilities (all in the area of setting it up [as new language](https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/blob/master/Modules/CMakeAddNewLanguage.txt)). I will certainly add the `ExternalProject_Add()` approach where you won't have to call the configuration twice manually (but where it would be - from my point of view - preferable to split your `CMakeLists.txt` file).

Comment: Perhaps also consider the approach described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36084785/1938798) where an executable needs to be built within the CMake run so it can be used to generate sources and even other CMakeLists.txt files. I have it working to generate files on OS X for an iOS build, so it works in practice for a situation like yours.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

CMake can only handle one compiler at a time. So - if you don't go the long way to set up the other compiler as a new language - you will end up with two configuration cycles.

I see the following approaches to automate this process:

1. Taking the example ["CMake Cross Compiling - Using executables in the build created during the build?"](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Cross_Compiling#Using_executables_in_the_build_created_during_the_build) from the CMake pages as a starting point I'll get:

   **CMakeLists.txt**

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
   project(FooBarTest)

   # When crosscompiling import the executable targets
   if (CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
       set(IMPORT_PATH "IMPORTFILE-NOTFOUND" CACHE FILEPATH "Point it to the export file path from a native build")
       file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "${IMPORT_PATH}" IMPORT_PATH_CMAKE)
       include(${IMPORT_PATH_CMAKE}/genfooTargets.cmake)

       # Then use the target name as COMMAND, CMake >= 2.6 knows how to handle this
       add_custom_command(
           OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.h
           COMMAND genfoo
       )

       add_executable(bar bar.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.h)
       target_include_directories(bar PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
   endif()

   # Only build the generator if not crosscompiling
   if (NOT CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
       add_executable(genfoo genfoo.cpp)
       export(TARGETS genfoo FILE "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/genfooTargets.cmake")
   endif()
   ```

   Then using a script like:

   **build.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   if [ ! -d hostBuild ]; then
       cmake -E make_directory hostBuild
       cmake -E chdir hostBuild cmake ..
   fi
   cmake --build hostBuild

   if [ ! -d crossBuild ]; then
       cmake -E make_directory crossBuild
       cmake -E chdir crossBuild cmake .. -DIMPORT_PATH=${PWD}/hostBuild -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake
   fi
   cmake --build crossBuild
   ```

   I'll get the desired results by calling `./build.sh`.
2. Splitting the `CMakeLists.txt` and maybe even replace the `export()`/`include()` with something where I know the output path of my build tools e.g. by using [`CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/variable/CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY.html) would simplify things:

   **CMakeLists.txt**

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
   project(FooBarTest)

   # Then use the target name as COMMAND. CMake >= 2.6 knows how to handle this
   add_custom_command(
       OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.h
       COMMAND genfoo
   )

   add_executable(bar bar.cpp ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/foo.h)
   target_include_directories(bar PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
   ```

   **buildTools/CMakeLists.txt**

   ```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
   project(BuildTools)

   add_executable(genfoo genfoo.cpp)
   ```

   **build.sh**

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   if [ ! -d crossBuild ]; then
       cmake -E make_directory crossBuild
       cmake -E chdir crossBuild cmake .. -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake
   fi
   if [ ! -d hostBuild ]; then
       cmake -E make_directory hostBuild
       cmake -E chdir hostBuild cmake ../buildTools -DCMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY:PATH=${PWD}/crossBuild
   fi
   cmake --build hostBuild
   cmake --build crossBuild
   ```

**References**

- *[Making a CMake library accessible by other CMake packages automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33462209/making-cmake-library-accessible-by-other-cmake-packages-automatically)*
- *[CMake build multiple targets in different build directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30999130/cmake-build-multiple-targets-in-different-build-directories)*
- *[How do I make CMake output into a 'bin' dir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6594796/how-do-i-make-cmake-output-into-a-bin-dir)*

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to do that completely within CMake.

The trick is to run a separate CMake configuring stage *within its own space*, silently dismissing every crosscompiling setting and using the host's default toolchain, then import the generated outputs into it's parent, crosscompiling build.

First part:

```
set(host_tools_list wxrc generate_foo)

if(CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    # Pawn off the creation of the host utilities into its own dedicated space
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/host_tools)
    file(TO_NATIVE_PATH ${CMAKE_COMMAND} native_cmake_command)
    file(TO_NATIVE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} native_cmake_current_source_dir)
    execute_process(
        COMMAND "${native_cmake_command}" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}" "${native_cmake_current_source_dir}"
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/host_tools
    )

    add_custom_target(host_tools
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build . --target host_tools --config $<CONFIG>
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/host_tools
    )
    include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/host_tools/host_tools.cmake)

    foreach(tgt IN ITEMS ${host_tools_list})
        add_dependencies(host${tgt} host_tools)
    endforeach()

else()
    # Add an empty target, host tools are built inplace
    add_custom_target(host_tools
        DEPENDS ${host_tools_list}
    )
endif()
```

... then you add the usual add_executable and whatever ...

At the end:

```
if(NOT CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING)
    foreach(tgt IN ITEMS ${host_tools_list})
        add_executable(host${tgt} ALIAS ${tgt})
    endforeach()

    export(TARGETS ${host_tools_list} NAMESPACE host FILE host_tools.cmake)
endif()
```

When it crosscompiles, it pawns off the creation of the host-run tools into its own dedicated space, and imports the targets as "hostwxrc" and "hostgenerate_foo", with a dependency on generating the host_tools *themselves* .

When it doesn't crosscompile, it builds wxrc and generate_foo as-is, and aliases them to hostwxrc and hostgenerate_foo.

After this, when you use `$<TARGET_FILE:wxrc>`, you refer to the wxrc built for the **target** platform, and `$<TARGET_FILE:hostwxrc>` refers to the wxrc built for the **host** platform, regardless whether they are the same or not.

Comment: It looks like with this approach you may need to clear CXX/CC environment vars, before calling host cmake with exec_process. i.e. `set(ENV{CXX} "")` and `set(ENV{CC} "")`