# Has CMake a build type for Profile?

Tags: cmake, profiler

CMake has several build types like Release, Debug, Release with debug info and Minimum size release. I was wondering if another build types can be added like Profile by users and if it is a well-known practice done by other programmers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You definitely can add your own build types. [Here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/-/wikis/FAQ#how-can-i-extend-the-build-modes-with-a-custom-made-one-) is the example of how to do it. Essentially, you just need to add all the variables like `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_XXX` with the suffix corresponding to your build type and of course update the `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` variable to account for the new type. Not sure how well-know this practice is(personally I never did it) but it certainly looks viable.

Comment: You may also want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24470998/1938798) for how to actually define and use different build types.