# libgit2 is not building in release mode on windows

Tags: libgit2

I am trying to build libgit2 in release mode on Windows 10 x64.

In my libgit2 directory, I run the following:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
cmake --build .
```

It still builds in debug mode, as far as I can tell. At least when I link it into a Visual Studio project it fails on debug assertions.

I have also tried

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 12 Win64" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
```

to no avail.

I even tried to get it working by including all of the `.vxcproj` files in my solution and building them all in release mode manually. No luck yet.

Is it supposed to be as simple as passing in the `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release` flag or am I missing something?

All I am really trying to do is keep the `git2.dll` from exploding on debug asserts when I run it. At least I think that is what is happening.

Here is the code I am trying to run from a Visual Studio 2013 project, where I linked in the `git2.lib` and referenced the `git2.dll` as mentioned [here](https://libgit2.github.com/docs/guides/build-and-link/)

```
#include "stdafx.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    const char *path = "C:/Dev/testing/brokenmerge";
    git_repository *repo = NULL;

    git_repository_open(&repo, path);

    printf("Opened repo: '%s'\n", path);

    git_repository_free(repo);

    return 0;
}
```

where `stdafx.h` includes `<git2.h>`

I get the following assertion error in `git_repository_open`:

```
Assertion failed!

Program: C:\Dev\testing\libgit2tests\Debug\git2.dll
File: C:\Dev\libgit2\src\global.c
Line: 202

Expression: git_atomic_get(&git__n_inits) > 0

For information on how your program can cause an assertion
failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts
```

So unless I linked to `git2` incorrectly or I am doing something else wrong I have no idea how to proceed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide an example of these asserts?  Can you provide an example of the code you're using that you're calling libgit2 with?

Comment: @EdwardThomson updated the question with a code snippet and the assertion!

Comment: Note that using `const char *path = "C:\\Dev\\testing\\brokenmerge";` doesn't make a difference either. Not that I thought it would, but I gave it a shot anyway.

Comment: You can provide the working directory and libgit2 will sort out the rest.  This is likely that you need to set up the global state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`git_libgit2_init`](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2#initialization) before calling any other libgit2 functions.  This sets up the global state that the library needs.

Answer (score 2):

I had this pain too.
The answer is

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

see [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE not being used in CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24460486/cmake-build-type-not-being-used-in-cmakelists-txt)