# Why is CMakePresets.json preventing --config argument for multiconfiguration CMake project?

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, cmake-presets

**tl;dr: why does Visual Studio Code not include `--config` argument to `cmake.exe` when my project has a `CMakePresets.json`?**

---

I'm transitioning from a primarily CLI-driven development environment to an IDE-driven development environment, and I'm having trouble understanding some interactions between the IDE and invoked CMake commands.

My original problem was that compiled binaries were being generated in unexpected locations.
E.g. for my (intended) Release build of Google Test, files like `gmock.lib` were being generated in a `Debug/` directory instead of the expected `Release/` directory.

I then traced this behavior to the presence/absence of the `--config` argument to `cmake.exe` as invoked by Visual Studio Code. From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24470998/5437543), I'm aware of the difference between single- and multi-configuration generators. I'm using the "Visual Studio 17 2022" generator, which is multi-configuration, so I'm aware that the user is expected to supply a `--config` argument at build time (otherwise, *I think/infer*, that "Debug" is chosen as the default configuration).

Specifically, I discovered that when my project has a `CMakePresets.json`, Visual Studio Code does not supply a `--config` argument to `cmake.exe` when building, and when there is no `CMakePresets.json`, Visual Studio Code does supply a `--config` argument.

I.e., when my project has no `CMakePresets.json`, this is Visual Studio Code's CMake command, as captured from the "OUTPUT" window:

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/dev/googletest/out/vscode/build --config Release --target ALL_BUILD -j 22 --
```

I also noticed that when there is no `CMakePresets.json`, under the "Configure" drop-down in the CMake pane, there is a "Release/Debug/etc." choice:
[image]

Coversely, when my project does have `CMakePresets.json`, this is Visual Studio Code's CMake command:

```
"C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build C:/dev/googletest/out/vscode/build/x64-release --parallel 22 --target ALL_BUILD
```

...i.e. there is no `--config` argument. Also, there is no "Release/Debug" choice in the "Configure" drop-down in the CMake pane:
[image]

This implicit presence/absence of the `--config` flag makes me not confident in the integrity of what I'm building: I feel like I'm creating some weird Debug/Release hybrid.

I'm newly learning CMake, and I've only just learned about the `CMakePresets.json`. I am probably mistaken, but I was under the impression that the CMake Presets only played a role in *CMake generation*, i.e. I don't understand why the presence/absence of `CMakePresets.json` impacts Visual Studio Code's decision whether to include `--config` in the *build*.

My question: **please explain what role `CMakePresets.json` plays in *building* a project, after CMake generation, and specifically how it interacts with "intelligent" IDEs, like Visual Studio Code, and if there a way I can both have `CMakePresets.json` and have the IDE correctly apply the `--config` build argument for multiconfiguration builds.**
(A reason why I'm particularly puzzled about the interaction with IDEs is if I both generate and build from the command line (i.e. not from the IDE), then I can explicitly specify the `--config` argument, regardless of the presence/absence of `CMakePresets.json`, in which case all output appears to be as expected (at least I do not observe any unexpected "Debug"s when I'm building Release")

This is the `CMakePresets.json`:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "windows-base",
      "description": "Target Windows with the Visual Studio development environment.",
      "hidden": true,
      "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/vscode/build/${presetName}",
      "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/vscode/install/${presetName}",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "gtest_force_shared_crt": {
          "type": "BOOL",
          "value":  "ON"
        }
      },
      "condition": {
        "type": "equals",
        "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
        "rhs": "Windows"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-debug",
      "displayName": "x64 Debug",
      "description": "Target Windows (64-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (Debug)",
      "inherits": "windows-base",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "x64",
        "strategy": "external"
      },
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" }
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-release",
      "displayName": "x64 Release",
      "description": "Target Windows (64-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (RelWithDebInfo)",
      "inherits": "windows-base",
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release" }
    },
    {
      "name": "x86-debug",
      "displayName": "x86 Debug",
      "description": "Target Windows (32-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (Debug)",
      "inherits": "windows-base",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "x86",
        "strategy": "external"
      },
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" }
    },
    {
      "name": "x86-release",
      "displayName": "x86 Release",
      "description": "Target Windows (32-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (RelWithDebInfo)",
      "inherits": "windows-base",
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release" }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> why does Visual Studio Code not include --config argument to cmake.exe when my project has a `CMakePresets.json`?

Because your (my) `CMakePresets.json` does not include a `buildPresets` section when it has specified a multi-configuration generator.

There are a few good answers on Stack Overflow that discuss what a generator is (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66845236/5437543) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24470998/5437543)). Essentially a generator is the build system for which CMake will generate build files. Examples of "build systems" are "Unix Makefiles" and "Visual Studio 17 2022." A build system has associated build files that describe how to go about doing the build: directories to descend into, source files, output files, and what compiler to use to turn source files to output files. The build files associated with the "Unix Makefiles" build system are `Makefiles`. The build files associated with "Visual Studio 17 2022" are `.sln` files (and possibly other associated files).

The process of building a CMake project is comprised of two steps: 1) the CMake configuration/generation, and 2) building the project.
CMake configuration/generation is itself comprised of two steps: configuration, and generation, but it is often discussed as though it were one stage, and different documentation will refer to this interchangeably as "configuration" or "generation." Configuration refers to the creation of the CMake cache, typically encapsulated in a file named `CMakeCache.txt` that effectively captures the state of CMake's analysis of the project's `CMakeList.txt` files, and various aspects of the build environment. Generation refers to the creation of the build system files based on the content of the CMake cache. I.e. if the generator is "Unix Makefiles," then generation will create `Makefile` files, and if the generator is "Visual Studio 17 2022," then generation will create `.sln` files (and possibly other associated files).
Building the project consists of running a build tool on the build files that were generated by the CMake generation. The build tool for "Unix Makefiles" is `make`, and the build tool for "Visual Studio 17 2022" is the Visual Studio IDE and the `msbuild` CLI-invokable command.

Build files may support multiple configurations or a single configuration.
Single configuration means that a given set of build files can only be used to build a specific configuration. I.e. the `Makefile` files created by one run of `cmake` can only be used to build the debug version of your hello-world application. Another run of `cmake`, that generates another discrete set of `Makefile` files, would be needed to build a release version of your application.
Multiple runs of `cmake` would overwrite the `Makefile` files from prior runs, unless you organized different directories for them, etc. In short: one build configuration per (set of) build file(s).
Multiple configuration means that one set of build files can be used to build multiple configurations. I.e. the `.sln` file created by one run of `cmake` could be used to build both debug and release versions of your application. In short: multiple build configurations per (set of) build file(s).

CMake only supports single configuration Makefiles.
Visual Studio solutions support multiple configurations.
<strike>CMake once treated Ninja as a single configuration generator, but was apparently updated to treat as a multiple configuration generator. (Confusing this issue during initial research is that lots of online documentation exists that still describes Ninja as a single-configuration generator)</strike> CMake once only offered the single-configuration "Ninja" generator, but was later updated to offer "Ninja Multi-Config", a multiple configuration generator that still targets the Ninja build tool.

> I was under the impression that the CMake Presets only played a role in CMake generation

This is incorrect. CMake Presets play a role in building the project for multiple configuration generators. Your (my) `CMakePresets.json` specified `"generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022"`, which is a multiple configuration generator. Your (my) `CMakePresets.json` only has a `configurePresets` section, which only feeds the CMake configuration/generation stage. You (I), similarly, need a section that feeds the build tool since the project, by virtue of choosing a multiple configuration generator, allows "multiple build configurations per (set of) build file(s)." That section, appropriately named, is "buildPresets".
**Importantly**, if you do not specify a `buildPresets` section when you have specified a multiple configuration generator, when you build, the default build configuration will be specified; this default build configuration is usually Debug, which aligns with your observation.

> The default Build Preset is equivalent to passing cmake --build with no other arguments from the command line.
> <sub>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-170</sub>

Here is an example `CMakePresets.txt`, inspired by https://github.com/esweet431/box2d-lite/blob/vs-launch/CMakePresets.json, that illustrates a `buildPresets` section:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "configurePresets": [
    {
      "name": "windows-base",
      "description": "Target Windows with the Visual Studio development environment.",
      "hidden": true,
      "generator": "Visual Studio 17 2022",
      "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/out/vs/build/${presetName}",
      "installDir": "${sourceDir}/out/vs/install/${presetName}",
      "cacheVariables": {
        "CMAKE_C_COMPILER": "cl.exe",
        "CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER": "cl.exe"
      },
      "condition": {
        "type": "equals",
        "lhs": "${hostSystemName}",
        "rhs": "Windows"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-debug",
      "displayName": "x64 Debug",
      "description": "Target Windows (64-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (Debug)",
      "inherits": "windows-base",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "x64",
        "strategy": "external"
      },
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" }
    },
    {
      "name": "x64-release",
      "displayName": "x64 Release",
      "description": "Target Windows (64-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (RelWithDebInfo)",
      "inherits": "x64-debug",
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release" }
    },
    {
      "name": "x86-debug",
      "displayName": "x86 Debug",
      "description": "Target Windows (32-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (Debug)",
      "inherits": "windows-base",
      "architecture": {
        "value": "x86",
        "strategy": "external"
      },
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug" }
    },
    {
      "name": "x86-release",
      "displayName": "x86 Release",
      "description": "Target Windows (32-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (RelWithDebInfo)",
      "inherits": "x86-debug",
      "cacheVariables": { "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release" }
    }
  ],
  "buildPresets": [
    {
      "name": "Debug",
      "displayName": "Debug",
      "configurePreset": "x64-debug",
      "configuration": "debug",
      "description": "Target Windows (64-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (Debug)"
    },
    {
      "name": "Release",
      "displayName": "Release",
      "configurePreset": "x64-release",
      "configuration": "release",
      "description": "Target Windows (64-bit) with the Visual Studio development environment. (RelWithDebInfo)"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: "I'm not sure if there is a command-line driven tool". There is, it is called `msbuild`.

Comment: "CMake once treated Ninja as a single configuration generator, but was apparently updated to treat as a multiple configuration generator. " 
That isn't quite correct. The single configuration generator "Ninja" still exists, they only added an additional "Ninja Multi-Config" generator that generates multi-config ninja files.

Comment: @Corristo - thank you for both comments! I've updated my answer accordingly.