# How to get the full build command in Visual Studio when build output and verbosity are already normal/detailed?

Tags: cmake, visual-studio-2022

I am configuring/building a CMake project (Google Test) in Visual Studio. I want to see the full command that is run to perform the build (I'm interested in verifying the state of the `--config` flag in the `cmake.exe` invocation, as related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77917086/5437543)).

The CMake output is already verbose appropriate to my needs: it shows the `cmake.exe` invocation (edited for brevity):

```
...
1>     PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
1>     VSAPPIDNAME=devenv.exe
1>     MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly=true
1> Command line: "C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe" /c "%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\chcp.com 65001 >NUL && "c:\program files\microsoft visual studio\2022\enterprise\common7\ide\commonextensions\microsoft\cmake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe"  -G "Visual Studio 17 2022"  -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:STRING="cl.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING="Debug" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="C:/dev/googletest/out/vs/install/x64-debug"   "C:\dev\googletest" 2>&1"
1> Working directory: C:/dev/googletest/out/vs/build/x64-debug
1> [CMake] -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
1> [CMake] -- Could NOT find Python3 (missing: Python3_EXECUTABLE Interpreter) 
...
```

Even though I have already explicitly set `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build And Run > MSBuild project build output and verbosity` to "Normal" (and then later to "Detailed") per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19848156/5437543)...
[image]
...the build output is sparse, and does not include any actual invoked commands:

```
>------ Build All started: Project: googletest, Configuration: x64-debug ------
  MSBuild version 17.8.5+b5265ef37 for .NET Framework
  
    1>Checking Build System
    Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/googlemock/CMakeLists.txt
    gtest-all.cc
    gmock-all.cc
    Generating Code...
    gmock.vcxproj -> C:\dev\googletest\out\vs\build\x64-debug\lib\Debug\gmock.lib
    Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/googlemock/CMakeLists.txt
    gtest-all.cc
    gmock-all.cc
    gmock_main.cc
    Generating Code...
    gmock_main.vcxproj -> C:\dev\googletest\out\vs\build\x64-debug\lib\Debug\gmock_main.lib
    Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/googletest/CMakeLists.txt
    gtest-all.cc
    gtest.vcxproj -> C:\dev\googletest\out\vs\build\x64-debug\lib\Debug\gtest.lib
    Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/googletest/CMakeLists.txt
    gtest_main.cc
    gtest_main.vcxproj -> C:\dev\googletest\out\vs\build\x64-debug\lib\Debug\gtest_main.lib
    Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/CMakeLists.txt

Build All succeeded.
```

I also don't see any difference in the build output between "Normal" and "Detailed" levels of verbosity.

In `Tools > Options > CMake > General`, I've also enabled the relevant-looking `Enable verbose CMake output` option.

My question is: **can Visual Studio (2022) be configured to output the actual command invoked when performing a build through the GUI?**
(I'm specifically interested in seeing (what I assume will be) `cmake.exe --build ... --config ...` invocations)

---

By way of comparison, here's the build output from Visual Studio Code, which does show the actual invoked command:

```
[main] Building folder: googletest 
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --build C:/dev/googletest/out/vs/build/x64-release --config release --target ALL_BUILD
[build] MSBuild version 17.8.5+b5265ef37 for .NET Framework
[build] 
[build]   1>Checking Build System
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/googlemock/CMakeLists.txt
[build]   gtest-all.cc
[build]   gmock-all.cc
[build]   Generating Code...
[build]   gmock.vcxproj -> C:\dev\googletest\out\vs\build\x64-release\lib\Release\gmock.lib
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/googlemock/CMakeLists.txt
[build]   gtest-all.cc
[build]   gmock-all.cc
[build]   gmock_main.cc
[build]   Generating Code...
[build]   gmock_main.vcxproj -> C:\dev\googletest\out\vs\build\x64-release\lib\Release\gmock_main.lib
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/googletest/CMakeLists.txt
[build]   gtest-all.cc
[build]   gtest.vcxproj -> C:\dev\googletest\out\vs\build\x64-release\lib\Release\gtest.lib
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/googletest/CMakeLists.txt
[build]   gtest_main.cc
[build]   gtest_main.vcxproj -> C:\dev\googletest\out\vs\build\x64-release\lib\Release\gtest_main.lib
[build]   Building Custom Rule C:/dev/googletest/CMakeLists.txt
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:11.905
[build] Build finished with exit code 0
[cpptools] The build configurations generated do not contain the active build configuration. Using "Debug" for CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE instead of "release" to ensure that IntelliSense configurations can be found
```